# sql diplays duplicate lines - need total instead

Tags: sql, teradata

When the query below is run, there are 2 identical lines for asset “1311”.  The table has 2 lines for distribution_type "DE" for this asset.  One line is for $ 13.25 for the current month depreciation and the second line is for $ 291.50 for a prior period adjustment.  What I'm trying to do is to modify the report so it displays 1 line for $ 304.75.

I think I’m getting 2 lines because of MAX but I’m not sure how to correct it to get 1 line with the total amount.  I've tried replacing MAX with SUM but that didn't work.  Thanks for the help.

```
WITH query_1_results AS

  (SELECT 
    ir.ERAC_BRANCH_LGCY_CD as ERACBR,
    pa.BUSINESS_UNIT, 
    pa.DESCR,
    pdr.DEPTID, 
    pdr.ASSET_ID, 
    pdr.ACCOUNT_AD,

  MAX(CASE WHEN ((pdr.FISCAL_YEAR =2015) AND (pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =11)) THEN  pdr.DEPR END) AS CURRENT_AMT,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ((pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015) AND (pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =10)) THEN pdr.DEPR  END) AS PRIOR_AMT

  FROM PSFS.PS_ASSET pa

INNER JOIN PSFS.PS_DEPR_RPT pdr 
ON pa.ASSET_ID = pdr.ASSET_ID
AND pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT

INNER JOIN INTGRT_RPT.DIM_LOCATION IR on pdr.deptid = ir.erac_branch_ps_org_cd and ir.curr_lrd_row_flg = 1

INNER JOIN RFS.STN_OPS_HIERARCHIES SOH ON pdr.deptid = soh.department

  WHERE 
    pa.BUSINESS_UNIT='A0150'
    AND pdr.BOOK='PERFORM'
    AND ((pdr.FISCAL_YEAR=  2015 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=11) 
    OR (pdr.FISCAL_YEAR=2015 AND pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD=10))
--and ( ? is null or soh.REGION_CD = ?)

  GROUP BY

    ir.ERAC_BRANCH_LGCY_CD,
    pa.business_unit,
    pa.descr,
    pdr.deptid,
    pdr.asset_id,
    pdr.account_ad)

  SELECT 
   q1.*,
    pdl.acct, 
    pdl.journal_id,
    pdl.journal_date

FROM query_1_results  q1

LEFT OUTER JOIN  psfs.ps_dist_ln pdl 
ON   pdl.asset_id = q1.asset_id
    AND  pdl.book = 'PERFORM'
    AND  pdl.business_unit ='A0150'
    AND  pdl.fiscal_year =2015
    AND  pdl.accounting_period =11
    AND  pdl.distribution_type = 'DE'

ORDER BY  q1.account_ad, q1.eracbr
```

Comment: `query_1_results` returns two rows, you could add both MAX using `MAX(CASE WHEN ((pdr.FISCAL_YEAR =2015) AND (pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =11)) THEN  pdr.DEPR ELSE 0 END) AS CURRENT_AMT +
  MAX(CASE WHEN ((pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = 2015) AND (pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =10)) THEN pdr.DEPR ELSE 0  END) AS AMT`, but you'll still get two rows. You seem to group by too many columns, but without knowing the uniqueness constraints it's hard to tell.

Comment: can you please show the two identical records so that we would be able to check the column causing the duplicate rows. Apparently it seems the the issue is with your q1* part. @Shaves

Comment: @Aritra Bhattattacharya...........Thanks..........I added a distinct to the second SELECT statement and that resolved the duplicate rows.  On the "MAX" lines, I added the DEPT field to DEPR_PDP field and got the total I was looking for.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @dnoeth..........Thanks for the suggestion.  I used a "distinct" to get rid of the duplicate rows.  One of the tables had multiple rows for a single asset and I was expecting this when we originally wrote the sql.  thanks for your help.....